# Accessing scope variable to indexin map object in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a sequence of day, an a foreach scope in a thymeleaf template, and also a hashmap object.

I want to access, hashmap values by the scope variable, but I can't figure out how. This is my best try so far:

```
      <td th:each="day : ${DaySequence}" class="openable" th:attr="data-redir=@{/task/frame/{nbrplt}/{week}/{day_num}(nbrplt=${vehicle.numberPlate}, week=${week.weekNumber}, day_num=${day}) }">
                    <ul>
                      <li th:each="task : ${vehicle.vehicleTaskByDays[day]}" th:text="${task.toString()}"></li>
                      <!-- <li th:text="${day}"></li> -->
                    </ul>
                  </td>
```

But thyme leaf can't parse this. On some forum i found this as solution:

```
  <li th:each="task : ${vehicle.vehicleTaskByDays[__${day}__]}" th:text="${task.toString()}"></li>
```

But it's does not work either, so how can i access the day variable between th "[ ]" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the get method of HasMap:

```
      <td th:each="day : ${DaySequence}" class="openable" th:attr="data-redir=@{/task/frame/{nbrplt}/{week}/{day_num}(nbrplt=${vehicle.numberPlate}, week=${week.weekNumber}, day_num=${day}) }">
                <ul>
                  <li th:each="task : ${vehicle.vehicleTaskByDays.get(day)}" th:text="${task.toString()}"></li>
                  <!-- <li th:text="${day}"></li> -->
                </ul>
              </td>
```